# Android Studio XML Error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-instant-apps

Currently testing out Android Instant Apps using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3 and I'm getting this error when I try to build the app and emulate it.
Any ways to fix it? (I'm making a multi-feature Instant App).

Error:

> ~/Documents/GitHub/AndroidInstantApp/android-topeka/topeka-ui/build/intermediates/manifests/full/feature/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:2
>   attribute 'split' in  tag is not a valid split name
>   Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link
>   failed: Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
>   Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':topeka-ui:processDebugFeatureResources'.
>
> > Failed to execute aapt

Comment: Please post your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: Here is my AndroidManifest.xml from the above path.

https://pastebin.com/JiqsvsHN

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think we may have found a bug of this alpha release.
I solved the problem by removing the dash ("-") from the module name:

Apparently it is not well supported for split names.

The strange part is, both the codelabs and my project were initially working correctly with the dash.

Comment: This resolved "attribute 'split' in <manifest> tag is not a valid split name" error

Comment: I removed the dashes from the module name but I get this error when running the app as an instant app.

https://pastebin.com/LnaHDijC

Comment: You should post another question for that with more context to try to uderstand what's happening. Also it would be nice if you can accept my answer since it solved your problem.